oauth 2 parameters can only have a single value: scope
I'm trying as a practical exercise connect Zoho apps with Google API, in this case I'm trying to connect with Google Sheets API. I'm connecting with OAuth2.0 Auth but when I connect the applications throw me this error:
enter image description here
and I was searching why the scope were duplicated but I don't find an answer, the Auth URL would be something like that:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=687208587690-aic82a1471cdp97m7s4j4bc15vfms00b.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets&access_type=offline&include_granted_scopes=true
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
I don't know if I configured wrong OAuth consent screen or configured wrong the params in Postman.
Update:
I will add more details
I'm trying to connect zoho expense with google sheets via API
In Zoho Expense I can connect with diferents custom services with this:
enter image description here
enter image description here
The ID client and secret client take them from the credentials of google cloud and with POSTMAN I generated the Auth URL with these parameters:
enter image description here
The URL access token:
enter image description here
The URL refresh token:
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. The sentence "Is connect correctly the apps between zoho and Google sheets" doesn't make sense from a language/grammar point of view.

The URL that you included is malformed. Querystring values including redirect_uri, scope should be URL-encoded not plaintext.

I encoded the redirect_uri and scope and the result is the same :(

I updated my issue with more details

Well, I found a solution, hope this can help another one:
The problem was not the scope, the problem was the parameter:
enter image description here
I change querystring by header:
enter image description here
And field the another fields with this:
Auth URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline
Access token: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Refresh token: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
And my URI from gy google acount: https://deluge.zoho.com/delugeauth/callback
